# Webapi exibir conteudo em uma view

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Ae pessoal, tudo bem?

Eu estou desenvolvendo minha primeira aplicação em `web api` `asp.net`.
E estou tendo dificuldades para exibir o conteúdo em uma `view`.

Controller:

```
public class ListaPresenteController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var produto = new Produtos();
            return Ok(produto.Listar());
        }
    }
```

Com esse código ele esta funcionando, mas só consegui exibir a lista de produtos na `home`, estou com dificuldades para configurar a `view` de produtos, e eu quero exibir a lista de produtos por exemplo na url: `www.meupai.com/produtos.`

Comment: Creio que a ideia de Web API não está bem compreendida. Web API não pressupõe que o resultado gerado será uma View, necessariamente. O resultado normalmente é um JSON, interpretado pela página chamadora, que pode ou não exibir uma View pra isso.

Comment: Hum, pode ser @CiganoMorrisonMendez mas ai entra a minha dúvida, como eu poderia criar uma view, onde a url dela seja www.meuapi.com/produtos e eu possa exibir e manipular (por exemplo em uma grid) o condeudo do JSON?

Comment: Você pode implementar um HTML estático e chamar os métodos da Web API utilizando JSON, que é o que os tutoriais de Web API sugerem: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu retorno tem que ser uma view, recomendo que use uma controller, como no exemplo abaixo. O webApi trabalha como um WS, dai o seu retorno e um json ou xml.

```
public class ListaPresenteController : Controller
{

}
```

Comment: Nesse caso ao invés de usar ApiController eu uso um controller?

Comment: Acredito que eu esteja perdido entre o controller mvc e o controller do webapi. E pretendo usar uma view para manipular, exibir os dados do json retornado do webapi.

Comment: Voce pode retornar direto os dados do json na sua action, a que irá passar os dados para a view ou na sua view chamar uma action que receba os dados do json.

Comment: Perdão, não consegui compreender direito, como retornar os dados direto em minha action?

Comment: Seria poderia fazer assim:

 public IList<Produtos> GetProdutos()
        {
            var produto = new Produtos();
            return (produto.Listar());
        }
Assim iria retornar direto para a sua view.

Comment: Valeu @thiago.adriano26 Hoje vou trabalhar nesse projeto mais tarde, ai vamos ver o resultado e posto aqui. Valeu e muito obrigado pela ajuda :)